# Convert IL code to C# at runtime

Tags: c#, il

Is there any **free** library that allows to transform IL code to C# at runtime?

Thanks,
Christian

**EDIT**

Here is an example of what I have:

In my program, at some point I have a list of strings which resemble the IL code of a class that lies in some assembly:

```
// =============== CLASS MEMBERS DECLARATION ===================

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit Probant.Arithmetics
       extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
  .method public hidebysig instance int32 
          Sum(int32 a,
              int32 b) cil managed
  {
    // Code size       11 (0xb)
    .maxstack  2
    .locals init ([0] int32 result,
             [1] int32 CS$1$0000)
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldarg.1
    IL_0002:  ldarg.2
    IL_0003:  add
    IL_0004:  stloc.0
    IL_0005:  ldloc.0
    IL_0006:  stloc.1
    IL_0007:  br.s       IL_0009

    IL_0009:  ldloc.1
    IL_000a:  ret
```

Now having this array of strings (each string a line), I would like to somehow generate corresponding C# code.

Does anyone know whether this is possible with **ILSpy**?

Comment: Maybe [Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0x241a0.aspx) would suit your needs? It allows emission of IL opcodes.

Comment: @Frédéric: Sounds like what he wants is the reverse...ie: given some IL code, it'll return the source code that would generate it.  Also known as a decompiler.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for something that will regenerate the code from IL. I only need very small methods to be reverse engineered, not entire classes or assemblies.

Comment: How much would you pay for such a library?

Comment: If requirement that source code must be decompiled at runtime is strict then you may use Reflector as it allows 14 days trial. Else you can use ILspy - it absolutely free.

Comment: @zproxy - it should be for free; @onehalftrackmindman I will check out ILspy, thanks for the info.

Comment: does it have to be at run time, or just something that is compiled?

Comment: it has to be at run time. I currently have the IL code in a List<string> object. I would also have access to the assembly containing the code I would like to transorf into c#.

Comment: I will edit my question to give an example

Comment: A decompiler as a service.  Nice twist.

Comment: If you like to do extra work you may create IL file in notepad then compile it in dll file by the ilasm utility and after that open that dll file by ILspy. But it much more easy to open dll which contains this code directly.

Comment: That's a really strange requirement, why do you want to do that? Why isn't using dotPeek directly sufficient?

Comment: Basically I have this code already in an assembly (also compiled using ilasm), do you know how to reverse engineer the assembly using ILSpy? I downloaded it, but I don't see how to use it. I can't find a manual or example code.

Comment: @svick - I will have a look at dotPeek (never heard of it), maybe that will do the trick

Comment: @Christian, it's basically the same as Reflector, which went pay-only recently.

Comment: @svick - great, I will use either that or ILSpy, I think one of them will offer what I need (probably both). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

ILSpy reads the input assemblies using Mono.Cecil and then works with the Cecils intermediate representation.

If you have the IL as a text rather then binary you would have to find something that can assemble the text into assembly or at least into the Cecils representation.

Answer (score 0):

As per me:

```
public int Sum(int a, int b)
{
    int result,CS$1$0000;
    result = a + b;
    CS$1$0000 = result;

    return CS$1$0000;
}
```

Comment: how is this an answer to the question?